# Facebook feed dialog language:

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to populate a feed dialog to post on friends / self wall however the language in the feed dialog is alien, below is the screen shot. Any ideas how I can change this to English?

[image]

I am not finding any problem in posting and hence I think posting code here is irrelevant, if it is necessary, please let me know and I will add the relevant code.